# How to use ng-if to show and hide on Boolean value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Struggling to find out what to put in the last span element where it says "I_DO_NOT_KNOW", this is my markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="key" translate>Label</div>
  <div class="value form-group">
    <input id="myId"
            class="form-control"
            type="text"
            name="nameAttrFoo"
            ng-model="vm.myModelValue"
            ng-blur="sanitizeInput(vm.myModelValue)"
            required 
    />
    </div>
<div class="value form-group pull-right" ng-hide="formName.nameAttrFoo.$untouched">
    <span class="note note-error"
            ng-show="formName.nameAttrFoo.$error.required"
            ng-hide="formName.nameAttrFoo.$dirty">
        Required field!
    </span>
    <span class="note note-error" ng-if="I_DO_NOT_KNOW">
        Number is bigger than this big prime!                
    </span>
</div>
```

and this is the function where I do a comparison, returning either true or false:

```
var boolie = false;
$scope.sanitizeInput = function(myModelValue) {
    var toInt = parseInt(myModelValue);
    var primeNr = 2147483647;

    if (toInt > primeNr) {
        boolie = true;
    } else {
        boolie = false;
    }
}
```

feeling like a complete imbecile here as I cannot for the life of me get my user-feedback line "Number is bigger than this big prime!" to display. I have tried a lot of things in the ng-if="I_DO_NOT_KNOW", please send help.

Comment: ng-if="any condition to check truth/falsely " option, the node will be visible. documentation is the key. "ng-if"="true"
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `boolie` in the scope for example:

```
$scope.boolie = false;
$scope.sanitizeInput = function(myModelValue) {
    var toInt = parseInt(myModelValue);
    var primeNr = 2147483647;

    if (toInt > primeNr) {
        $scope.boolie = true;
    } else {
        $scope.boolie = false;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
<span class="note note-error" ng-if="boolie">
```

If you don't want to set `boolie` in the scope, you can call directly your function, but since it is already called on the blur event, I think that's not what you want (it must work though):

```
<span class="note note-error" ng-if="sanitizeInput(vm.myModelValue)">
```

Hoping this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks, I should have known! For anyone else, do as i should have done and not as I did, and read the docs on scope @ https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope